# Finding pairs of variables sequentially from a vector input

Tags: r

I have a table that looks like:

```
Individual<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
a<-c(1,1,1,2,2)
b<-c(1,2,3,3,4)
```

I am trying to get R to find pairs between columns a and b so I have used `Pairs<-x[x$a==1,"b"]` which will tell me that `Pairs= 1,2,3` from column b are paired with 1 in column a.

The problem I am having is that then I want it to look for pairs in the other direction. So I then want to look for 1 then 2 then 3 from column b **paired with something that is not the original query in column a**. So here searching with 1 and 2 would give nothing but 3 would output "2". I'd like the final output to be something like:

```
(1,3)
(2,3)
```

I have tried code like

```
test<-x[x$a==1,"b"]
x[x$b%in%test,"a"]
```

but this just gives all of the values that match in column a with 1, 2, and 3 from column b -- it does not distinguishing which is which. If I could have it run each integer in "test" sequentially that might work...

```
for(n in Pairs) print(x[x$b==n,"a"])
```

this code out puts the sets of pairs separately, but i'm unsure how to capture this data so that it could be used to do the same sort of thing again.

Comment: Define what you mean by 'pair'. `1,3`, `2,3` are not 'pairs' under the conventional definition.

Comment: I mean values that are from the same individual (row).